# Bundler throws No Such file or directory for gem install

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, backup, bundler

In Gemfile,

```
gem "backup", :git => "git://github.com/tenmiles/backup.git", :ref => "develop"
```

n local and in staging, `bundle install` did finish successfully. In production, when `bundle install --deployment` happens, bundler throws this error

```
Using backup (3.0.19) from git://github.com/tenmiles/backup.git (at develop)
/usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/installer.rb:365:in `initialize': No such file or directory - /home/anand/public_html/myapp/releases/20111113170352/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bundler/gems/gems/backup-3.0.19/bin/backup (Errno::ENOENT)
```

I checked in `/home/anand/public_html/myapp/releases/20111113170352/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bundler/gems/gems/` and backup-150fb5168ebe is there! Its a gem installed via git. why is bundler looking for backup-3.0.19. How can I refresh backup gem and ask bundler to re install the gem from scratch.

Please help

Answer (score 1):

Try this http://raflabs.com/blogs/silence-is-foo/2010/07/19/installing-a-gem-fork-from-github-source/  U can install the gem into your gem set by the method mentioned in there

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue with 1.0.10, but when I updated the servers to bundler 1.0.21 the problem went away.

Answer (score 0):

i have the some problem with current spork. If you specify a version it should work

```
gem "backup", '1.0', :git => "git://github.com/tenmiles/backup.git"
```

it fixed it for me